# Accessing PIL image subelements, and taking a string from it

Tags: python, string, variables, python-imaging-library

At the moment i have an image that i would just like to sample a single string out of the example outlines the details below (Assume the image has been loaded into memory for PIL access)

```
# Image size of: Image[480,640] (Binary image for example)
# Take string from level (y = 200) from start to (x = 250)
Sample_binary = Image[x:1,y]
```

but when i try to access this its throwing up an error asking for just an integer (so as i understand it, it doesn't use [Python Strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) possibly??), which means i can only access one pixel, is there anyway i can sample a line from the start of the image Row (x = 0 to x = 250) on Column (y = 200)?

Thankyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

Without using the numpy arrays:

```
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open("basic_training.png")

# get a line
def get_line(i, y):
    pixels = i.load() # this is not a list, nor is it list()'able
    width, height = i.size
    all_pixels = []
    for xPos in range(width):
        cpixel = pixels[xPos, y]
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)
    return all_pixels

# get a columns
def get_column(i, x):
    pixels = i.load() # this is not a list, nor is it list()'able
    width, height = i.size
    all_pixels = []
    for yPos in range(height):
        cpixel = pixels[x, yPos]
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)
    return all_pixels

line = get_line(i, y)
print len(line)
col = get_column(i, x)
print len(col)
```

get_line gives a line, given the y position of it 
get_col gives a column given the x position of it

your description of string, image, etc was kind of confusing. Did not know if you want only one pixels, the whole line, etc. With the code above, as it returns a normal python list, you can `','.join(col)` them or the way you need them.

Comment: Sorry i mean i was just noting the size of the image in pixels, really should of said that differently

Answer (score 0):

Using the tutorial for reference: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Image.jpg")
box = (0, 200, 251, 201) # (left, upper, right, lower)
region = im.crop(box)
L = region.load()
```

This lets you retrieve RGB bytes from your retrieved line of data:

```
>>> L[0, 0]
(98, 92, 44)
>>> L[250, 0]
(104, 97, 43)
```

And just to show the size limits:

```
>>> L[0, 1] # out of bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: image index out of range
>>> L[251, 0] # out of bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: image index out of range
```